# VS SSRS 2017 automated DAX bringing no results but fetching results in query designer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2017

Today I had to upgrade my developer edition of SQL Server, going from 2014 to 2017.

With this I also had to upgrade our reports using SSDT 2017. Our old report datasets where in MDX format, and it had no measures defined, which 2017 really kicked off about when we tried running them.

Unfortunately we could not remove them using Query designer, so had to delete the DS and we create it. The MDX didn't bring back any data in query designer, but DAX did, so we went with that option.

However, every time we run it in previewer and on our server, no data is returned. Below is the code that was created by Query Designer.

```
DEFINE VAR ArchiveArchiveId1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@ArchiveArchiveId) = 1, 
IF(@ArchiveArchiveId <> "", @ArchiveArchiveId, BLANK()), 
IF(PATHITEM(@ArchiveArchiveId, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@ArchiveArchiveId, 2), 
BLANK()))
VAR ArchiveArchiveId1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@ArchiveArchiveId) > 1 && 
PATHITEM(@ArchiveArchiveId, 1, 1) < 1
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Archive'[ArchiveId], 'Archive'[Block Name], 
'Archive'[Comments], 'Archive'[Condition], 'Archive'[Consequence], 
'Archive'[Element], 'Archive'[Facet], 'Archive'[HasPhoto], 
'Archive'[Likelihood], 'Archive'[Local Department Name Whole Block], 
'Archive'[Photo Filename], 'Archive'[Remaining Life Yrs], 'Archive'[Remedial 
Action], 'Archive'[Risk], 'Archive'[SiteName], 'Archive'[Sub Element], 
'Archive'[Year], FILTER(VALUES('Archive'[ArchiveId]), ((ArchiveArchiveId1ALL || 'Archive'[ArchiveId] = ArchiveArchiveId1))))
```

If anybody has any suggestions on how to manually change that to get it to actually work live and not just in query designer that would be great (taking out the parameter works but we need it in as we have a lot of archive ids).

Thanks in advance